# Reject a git commit with a message that is the same as that of the previous commit?

Tags: git

So, I occasionally make the mistake of pressing the up key one time too many or few and end up doing `git commit -am "changed foo"` instead of `./foo_test`, resulting in extra commits in my repo that I then have to deal with. Is it possible to have git reject any commit whose message matches the message of the previously committed commit?

Comment: Just as a side note: `git commit -a` is not considered to be a good practice anyway. It is recommended to review what are you going to commit every time, so the common workflow would be to do `git status`, then `git add <files>` or `git add -a`, and then `git commit`.

Comment: You could set up a pre-commit hook, a la http://mark-story.com/posts/view/using-git-commit-hooks-to-prevent-stupid-mistakes Although in this case it may just be easier to undo it, as suggested.

Answer (score 6):

Rather than rejecting it outright, why not just undo it?

```
# Leaves all changes as 'changes to be committed', but
# uncommits the most recent commit
git reset --soft HEAD~
# Leaves all changes as changed working copy files (ie,
# unstages them as well)
git reset HEAD~
# Lets you edit the most recent commit message 
git commit --amend
# Lets you do bulk surgery on your revision history, deleting
# or merging dozens of commits in one operation
git rebase -i <last good commit, eg origin/mainline>
```

If you really want this to be rejected outright, check out `.git/hooks/prepare-commit-msg` - you can add a script there to get the latest commit message (via `git cat-file commit HEAD`) and compare it to the commit message passed in. If they match, `exit 1` to abort the commit.

Answer (score 0):

Use post-commit hook script to check.

If same, then git reset --mixed HEAD~1